# Add an option to context menu in vscode (only to workspace folders)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I read the vscode API documentation here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus and found that I can identify the folder in the "when" clause, but I am not able to find any API which allows me to identify if this is a folder present in the workspace.

To identify if it's a folder, I use "explorerResourceIsFolder" context name from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.

I would like to know a way in which I can identify that the folder is a workspace folder and then I will be able to add an option to the context menu.

Example: In this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces, I want to add an option to the context menu when you click on the folder "vscode", "vscode-docs", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is a when clause "explorerResourceIsRoot" which can be used for this scenario. This is definitely not in the documentation as the list is not exhaustive as mentioned in the documentation.

I found it from the keybindings(there are when clauses mentioned for various commands) in vscode which you can navigate using the information here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_default-keyboard-shortcuts or simply do CTRL+SHIFT+P, search for keyboard shortcuts.